# acumatica "how can I save original record by clicking "OK" button in Grid"

Tags: acumatica

I have created grid in one tab and taken `NoteID` field in DAC. By adding `NoteID` I can see Attachment Column (where I can upload files) in the grid.

After filling all the column field, when I click Attachment I can see popup message

> The changes need to be saved. Do you want to proceed?

When I click "OK" button it saves two records (two rows) in the Grid.

Can any one suggest me how can I save original record by clicking "OK" button.

Comment: It would be best to include code examples so people can see what you have tried to better recommend answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

"***The changes need to be saved. Do you want to proceed?***" message pops up during an attempt to attach files to inserted (and not yet saved in database) record. By clicking **OK** on the "***The changes need to be saved. Do you want to proceed?***" dialog, you save all the changes users made so far on the screen.

Hope this helps... Code examples and screenshots will definitely help better understand your question.